# Select only players who have played a specific game and no other games

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to SQL and I'm stumped on a query I'm trying to make. I have a dataset similar to this

Player

```
masterID   firstName   lastName
11111      Rob         Caspian
22222      Bob         Harper
33333      Jon         Willow
44444      Ron         Anderson
55555      Doug        Blake
```

Appearances

```
masterID   gameName
11111      chess
11111      checkers
11111      chess
22222      chess
22222      chess
33333      monopoly
33333      monopoly
33333      monopoly
44444      chess
55555      risk
55555      chess
```

I want to return all player's first names and last names who only played chess and no other game. So it should return Bob Harper and Ron Anderson.

```
SELECT player.firstName, player.lastName from player, appearances where player.masterID = appearances.masterID and appearances.gameName = "chess";
```

I have a query that would return everyone who ever played chess no matter what other games they played but I can't figure out how to limit it to the players who only played chess. It should also only return player's names once. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add another filter towards the end of the query to filter out MasterID's that appear in other games:

```
SELECT player.firstName, player.lastName 
from player
join appearances on player.masterID = appearances.masterID  
where appearances.gameName = 'chess'
and masterID not in(select masterID from Appearances where gameName != 'chess')
```

Comment: Ugh, hate it when I'm almost done with an answer, the "a new answer" box pops up, and it's almost word for word what I was typing.  Have an upvote

Comment: @Kevin I know where you are coming from. Thanks.

Comment: @isaace thanks for your quick answer. You have taught me something new about SQL! I will need to add DISTINCT and also an ORDER BY at the end but your solution is working great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the result by just using a [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) and [aggregation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) as illustrated below.

```
SELECT A.firstName, A.lastName
FROM Player A LEFT JOIN Appearances B
ON A.masterID=B.masterID
GROUP BY A.firstName, A.lastName
HAVING SUM(B.gameName = 'chess')=COUNT(*);
```

See it [run on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d356cf/1).

Comment: I didn't know SQL Fiddle existed. That's sweet! thanks